# Spring Security Context not set after Keycloak authentication

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to integrate Spring Boot with Keycloak.

application.properties

```
keycloak.realm=Helpdesk
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.resource=helpdesk
keycloak.credentials.secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig : KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
    }

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider()
        val simpleAuthorityMapper = SimpleAuthorityMapper()
        simpleAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("")
        simpleAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true)
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(simpleAuthorityMapper)
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider)
    }

    @Bean
    override fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy {
        return RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistryImpl())
    }

    @Bean
    fun keycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakConfigResolver {
        return KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()
    }

}
```

SignInService

```
@Service
class AuthenticationService(private val keycloakRequestConfig: KeycloakRequestConfig) {

    fun signIn(signInRequest: SignInRequest): AccessTokenResponse {
        logger.info { ">>>>>>> User ${signInRequest.username} logs in" }
        val authClient: AuthzClient = AuthzClient.create(keycloakRequestConfig)
        val response: AccessTokenResponse = authClient.obtainAccessToken(signInRequest.username, signInRequest.password)
        logger.info { "<<<<<<< User ${getCurrentLoggedUserId()} logged" }
        return response
    }
}
```

After authentication I receive JWT token but when I try to call  `val authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication as KeycloakAuthenticationToken` in getCurrentLoggedUserId() i receive an error:  `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken`

What I do wrong? I receive JWT token from Keycloak with all Roles and other informations but SecurityContext is empty.

Comment: Check your logs what you are getting back cant be cast, so what you are getting back is not what you expected.